# Android Studio: How to list files whose line count is bigger than N, e.g. N=400

Tags: android, regex, android-studio

I would like to get a list of files whose line count >=400. How to do that?
I have tried to use search with regex options, but in vain.

Any idea on how to do this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Try by installing [Statistic](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4509) plugin in your Android studio. So that you can view the individual and all the file information (like number of lines of code and size etc.) in one place like below.

[image]

Comment: This works to some degree. But what I want to get is a list of file only when it has more than N lines.

Comment: you can sort by total lines of code and can get all the files greater than N in once place right?

Comment: Upvoted! Though not ideal answer, at least it worked.

Comment: You can write a java code to get files which meets your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to read it is to read each file fully or at least until you reach the 400 lines. The second solution is better, because that way you don't always need to read the whole file, so it's faster.

To do that, you should use a buffer byte array and analyze each read character.

Using a regex for it is not always the best idea, because it's way slower, than checking each character manually.

So the regex for that will be something like this: `([^\n]*\n){400,}`

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work fully. It identified two files in my case, whose length is 400+ lines, but there are other files missing.

Comment: This regex should detect ALL the files which has 400+ lines, it also counts the empty lines as new lines.

Comment: From my tests, no. only a few files are listed.